# TensorBoard Distributions and Histograms with Keras and fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm using Keras to train a CNN using the fit_generator function.

It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3358) that TensorBoard doesn't show histograms and distributions in this setup.

Did anybody figure out a way to make it work anyway?

Answer (score 11):

There is no easy way to just plug it in with one line of code, you have to write your summaries by hand.

The good news is that it's not difficult and you can use the [TensorBoard callback code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks_v1.py) in Keras as a reference.
(There is also a [version 2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py) ready for TensorFlow 2.x.)

Basically, write a function e.g. `write_summaries(model)` and call it whenever you want to write your summaries (e.g. just after your `fit_generator()`)

Inside your `write_summaries(model)` function use `tf.summary`, `histogram_summary` and other summary functions to log data you want to see on tensorboard.

If you don't know exactly how to check [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard):
and this great example of [MNIST with summaries](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py).

Answer (score 1):

I believe bartgras's explanation is superseded in more recent versions of Keras (I'm using Keras 2.2.2).  To get histograms in Tensorboard all I did was the following, (where `bg` is a data wrangling class which exposes a generator for `gb.training_batch()`; `gb.validation_batch()` however is NOT a generator):

```
NAME = "Foo_{}".format(datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds')).replace(':', '-')

tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME),
    histogram_freq=1,
    write_images=True)

callbacks = [
    tensorboard
]

history = model.fit_generator(
    bg.training_batch(),
    validation_data=bg.validation_batch(),
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=bg.steps_per_epoch,
    validation_steps=bg.validation_steps,
    verbose=1,
    shuffle=False,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: What is the NAME here?

Comment: I am using Keras 2.2.4, but still `ValueError: If printing histograms, validation_data must be provided, and cannot be a generator.`

Comment: @thebeancounter The name of your run. You could make it your hyperparameters or something human-readable.

Comment: -1 for non-informative code. What are `bg`, `training_batch()`, `validation_batch()`? We can't even tell if you are passing a generator or something else.