# TensorBoard Distributions and Histograms with Keras and fit_generator in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

Related to this issue:

[TensorBoard Distributions and Histograms with Keras and fit_generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425858/tensorboard-distributions-and-histograms-with-keras-and-fit-generator/42477664)

I am looking for a similar solution with `TensorBoardWrapper` which I am not able to find in the R implementation.

Is there a solution for the histogram problem with fit_generator in keras for R?